# Magento: Set default store view for customer groups

Tags: php, magento

I really really can't seem to find a way to set a specific store view for a customer group.
I have 1 view showing prices including VAT and 1 view showing prices without VAT.

Now I want my group of resellers to automaticly view the store in the "resellers store view" so they see the prices w/o VAT.

There seems to be no way of doing this!

Thanks in advance!

### Edit

Thanks!

I inserted @Jakub Korupczyński code in the index.php but just after the Mage::run()
And now its working!

I indeed think it will be better to make an extention for this, so I'm in the process of learing it. But in the mean time this will do!

### Edit2

Seems it not working after all. The code after Mage::Run is not reached...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a new extension with observer.

For Instance I created extension Jakkor_Setstore. So the folders looked like this:

```
app/code/local/Jakkor
app/code/local/Jakkor/Setstore
app/code/local/Jakkor/Setstore/etc
app/code/local/Jakkor/Setstore/Model
```

In etc there was a file "config.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <setstoreobserver>
                  <class>Setstore_Model</class>
           </setstoreobserver>
        </models>
     </global>
     <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch>
                <observers>
                    <jakkor_setstore_model_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Jakkor_Setstore_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>setstore</method>
                    </jakkor_setstore_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch>
       </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

In Model there is a file "Observer.php":

```
class Jakkor_Setstore_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
  public function setstore($observer)
  {
      if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
      {
        $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(); //get the group id
        if($groupId == 2) //I don't know what id has your reseller group, so 2 is an example, you need to set here the specific group
        {
          Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(2); //Set id of the store view without vat
        }
        else {
          Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(1); //set the store view with vat
        }
      }
  }
}
```

And of course in app/etc/modules "Jakkor_Setstore.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Jakkor_Setstore>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Jakkor_Setstore>
    </modules>
</config>
```

This was tested and it is working. Sorry for the mess before. I didn't test the first approach. I thought that it should work.

Comment: Mage:: factory calls won't work before Mage::run.  He should put `Mage::app()` above the first Mage::.

Comment: @seanbreeden How should I do that? I tried it but now I get a blank page when looking at index.php

Comment: Ok, sorry, I changed to "after". Thank you for accepting answer.

Comment: Whoops.. after some intensive testing; this is not working.. the code after Mage::Run is not reached...

Comment: Try putting `Mage::app();` on the line before `if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())`.  You can't put anything after `Mage::run();`

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please try it now. I hope that this time it will work :)

Comment: Works fine with my CE 1.8.1. Thank you. It might also be worthwhile to note that you can use `$groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
   $taxId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/group')->getTaxClassId($groupId);` to check for the tax class instead. So your end user can add additional wholesale customer groups in that tax class without you having to update your observer.