# Store View depending customer group

Tags: magento, store

I use the module from this post [Magento: Set default store view for customer groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813576/magento-set-default-store-view-for-customer-groups)

Can anybody help me with the **code**.
We have 3 customer groups (Id 4, 5, 6) that should see store 2 (without tax) and 2 customer groups (Id 2,3) and the "notlogged in" (Id 0) customer that should see store 1 (with tax)

Comment: can you elaborate more that what do you want to implement?

Comment: Of course, we got 6 customer groups and two store views. We use our store view not for language, we use it for display prices and order incl. tax and prices and order excl. tax. Now we would like to give access to a store view depending on customer group. For example customer group 0 (not logged in) and CG 1 and CG 2 sees the default store view 1, no access to store view 2. CG 3, CG 4 and CG 5 sees the store view 2, no access to store view 1 if there are logged in. This is a solution for b2c and b2b store in one with one registration for all –